# PHP POST requires filename in POST URL?

Tags: php, post

My problem is simple. When I POST to this url:
http://domain.com/login

...PHP does not receive any post values. But if I simply change the post url to:
http://domain.com/login/index.php

...it works.

Please note that if you browse any directory, it will automatically load the index.php file by default. For example, loading "http://domain.com/login/" in your address bar will indeed load the index.php page. It's just that POST'ing does not working unless I specify the filename.

Anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have a different directory index specified for `/login/` inside your HTACCESS file?

Comment: How about `http://domain.com/login/` instead of `http://domain.com/login`?

Comment: Wow, @sjagr, you're right. I need the trailing slash. Can't believe I didn't think of that... If you add as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `http://domain.com/login` instead of `http://domain.com/login/`, the server tries to load the file `login` explicitly inside of your document root instead of the index file located within the `login` directory. Make sure you include the trailing slash!